# "Error: Could not find or load main class jdk1.8.0_111"

Tags: java

I am new to java, i trying to run as java application in my eclipse. But i am getting `Error: Could not find or load main class jdk1.8.0_111`. I have `jdk1.8.0_111` and `jre1.8.0_111`.

What does this mean, what causes it, and how should you fix it?

Comment: Can you post your code?  Seems like your code does not have a main method.

Comment: It means it can't find or load the main class. Which class are you trying to execute? How? What is its code?

Comment: It could also mean that you have garbled the `java` command line

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your problem more clearly? You may be java is not installed successfully, if you sure the installation is successful, cmd input "java" will be prompted, please make sure you install java success.